# Checking whether multiple resources exists using existenceCondition in Azure policy

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-policy, azure-monitor

I am trying to bring up an azure policy to create alert rules for a specific type of resource when there are desired alert rules already not defined for the particular resource. For that i used deployIfNotExists effect and existenceCondition with anyOf.

But it is not working as expected. Need some help on this if someone already handled similar scenario for your usecase.

```
    "then": {
    "effect": "deployIfNotExists",
    "details": {
      "type": "microsoft.insights/metricAlerts",
      "resourceGroupName": "[resourceGroup().name]",
      "existenceCondition": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "field": "name",
            "equals": "[concat('alert_appgw_failedrequests_',field('Name'))]"
          },
          {
            "field": "name",
            "equals": "[concat('alert_appgw_throughput_',field('Name'))]"
          },
          {
            "field": "name",
            "equals": "[concat('alert_appgw_unhealthyhost_',field('Name'))]"
          }
        ]
      },
      "roleDefinitionIds": [
        "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
      ],
      "deployment": {
```

This is not working as expected, this is actually metricalert resource i try to create if not exists for appgateway, if i delete any one of the metricalert alone for an appgateway it is not creating an alertrule/metric alert.

I need to create a metricalert if even any one of the metric alert is deleted or not exists for a appgateway.

Someone help out with your ideas,

PS: Please correct me if this query is not clear enough.

Edit:

Posting the full definition, Actually, i am getting non-compliant resources as compliant too. @Niclas

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways"
        },
        {
          "field": "tags.nomonitor",
          "exists": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deployIfNotExists",
      "details": {
        "type": "microsoft.insights/metricAlerts",
        "resourceGroupName": "[resourceGroup().name]",
        "existenceCondition": {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "field": "name",
              "equals": "[concat('alert_appgw_failedrequests_',field('Name'))]"
            },
            {
              "field": "name",
              "equals": "[concat('alert_appgw_throughput_',field('Name'))]"
            },
            {
              "field": "name",
              "equals": "[concat('alert_appgw_unhealthyhost_',field('Name'))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
        ],
        "deployment": {
          "properties": {
            "mode": "incremental",
            "template": {
              "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
              "parameters": {
                "appgateway_name": {
                  "type": "String"
                },
                "location": {
                  "type": "String"
                }
              },
              "resources": [
                {
                  "type": "microsoft.insights/metricAlerts",
                  "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
                  "name": "[concat('alert_appgw_failedrequests_',parameters('appgateway_name'))]",
                  "location": "global",
                  "properties": {
                    "description": "Platform alerts",
                    "severity": 2,
                    "enabled": true,
                    "scopes": [
                      "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/',parameters('appgateway_name'))]"
                    ],
                    "evaluationFrequency": "PT15M",
                    "windowSize": "PT15M",
                    "criteria": {
                      "allOf": [
                        {
                          "threshold": 10,
                          "name": "Metric1",
                          "metricNamespace": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
                          "metricName": "FailedRequests",
                          "operator": "GreaterThanOrEqual",
                          "timeAggregation": "Total",
                          "criterionType": "StaticThresholdCriterion"
                        }
                      ],
                      "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria"
                    },
                    "autoMitigate": true,
                    "targetResourceType": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
                    "targetResourceRegion": "[parameters('location')]",
                    "actions": [
                      {
                        "actionGroupId": "/subscriptions/ec23feef-629f-481d-b69e-a5d7faa5cb26/resourceGroups/DefaultResourceGroup-WUS2/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/ALERT-DL",
                        "webHookProperties": {}
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "type": "microsoft.insights/metricAlerts",
                  "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
                  "name": "[concat('alert_appgw_throughput_',parameters('appgateway_name'))]",
                  "location": "global",
                  "properties": {
                    "description": "Platform alerts",
                    "severity": 2,
                    "enabled": true,
                    "scopes": [
                      "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/',parameters('appgateway_name'))]"
                    ],
                    "evaluationFrequency": "PT15M",
                    "windowSize": "PT15M",
                    "criteria": {
                      "allOf": [
                        {
                          "threshold": 1000,
                          "name": "Metric1",
                          "metricNamespace": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
                          "metricName": "Throughput",
                          "operator": "GreaterThan",
                          "timeAggregation": "Average",
                          "criterionType": "StaticThresholdCriterion"
                        }
                      ],
                      "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria"
                    },
                    "autoMitigate": true,
                    "targetResourceType": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
                    "targetResourceRegion": "[parameters('location')]",
                    "actions": [
                      {
                        "actionGroupId": "/subscriptions/ec23feef-629f-481d-b69e-a5d7faa5cb26/resourceGroups/DefaultResourceGroup-WUS2/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/ALERT-DL",
                        "webHookProperties": {}
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "type": "microsoft.insights/metricAlerts",
                  "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
                  "name": "[concat('alert_appgw_unhealthyhost_',parameters('appgateway_name'))]",
                  "location": "global",
                  "properties": {
                    "description": "Platform alerts",
                    "severity": 2,
                    "enabled": true,
                    "scopes": [
                      "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/',parameters('appgateway_name'))]"
                    ],
                    "evaluationFrequency": "PT15M",
                    "windowSize": "PT15M",
                    "criteria": {
                      "allOf": [
                        {
                          "threshold": 1,
                          "name": "Metric1",
                          "metricNamespace": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
                          "metricName": "UnhealthyHostCount",
                          "operator": "GreaterThanOrEqual",
                          "timeAggregation": "Average",
                          "criterionType": "StaticThresholdCriterion"
                        }
                      ],
                      "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria"
                    },
                    "autoMitigate": true,
                    "targetResourceType": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
                    "targetResourceRegion": "[parameters('location')]",
                    "actions": [
                      {
                        "actionGroupId": "/subscriptions/ec23feef-629f-481d-b69e-a5d7faa5cb26/resourceGroups/DefaultResourceGroup-WUS2/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/ALERT-DL",
                        "webHookProperties": {}
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "parameters": {
              "appgateway_name": {
                "value": "[field('Name')]"
              },
              "location": {
                "value": "[field('Location')]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: You should post the whole policy definition, it will be easier to recreate and test. The issue could be with your if statement or in your deployment, but we wouldn't know. Do you get non-compliant resources in your compliance overview or does it show 0?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-metric-create-templates

Comment: @Niclas Thanks for checking it, added details as edit in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `existenceCondition` you are checking if `anyOf` the three conditions evaluates to true. This is the case as long as at least one metricAlert exists.

I am think you should be able to solve it using `count`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/author-policies-for-arrays